# Spring Data Rest, Many to one

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest

I'm building an application using Spring Data Rest. i have a Many to One relationship backed by a non-nullable foreign key. Which is the correct way to add an element on the "Many" side of the relationship using the REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to work:

```
POST http://server:8080/context/manyEntity

{"manyId":"manyIdValue","manyAttribute1":"manyAttribute1Value",...,"oneEntity":{"oneId":"oneIdValue"}}
```